# Store the output of pig job into a directory structure derived from data

Tags: apache-pig, store, derived, output-directory

I would like to achieve the following:

My input data looks as follows

```
{"metadata":
{
"producerName":"capture_api",
"producerVersion":"3.0.13"
},
"payload":
{
--some payload 
}
}
```

I would like to bucket this data using a pig script as follows

```
/finalOutputDir/producerName/producerVersion/File.txt
```

Is there a way I can do this. I have tried using the MultiStorage Function but that class supports only one field. I can override the functionality inside multistage but just wanted to check if there is a easier option.

Comment: So i solved this problem as follows:                                                rawJsonData = LOAD 'data' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad'); namedJsonData = FOREACH rawJsonData GENERATE CONCAT($0#'metadata'#'producerName',CONCAT('/',$0#'metadata'#'producerVersion'))‌​,$0#'payload';STORE namedJsonData INTO 'finalOutputDir' USING MultiStorage('/data/fridge/flume/rl.Q.data_event/', '0', 'none', ','); Adding a column like producerName/producerVersion to data actually wrote it in a directory structure

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer box below, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The piggybank [MultiStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html) could separate the data into multiple folders by a (only one?) field.

```
STORE data INTO '$out/$producerName' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('$out/$producerName', '0', 'none', ',');
```